# How to redirect grep output to a variable?

Tags: bash, variables, grep, output, pipe

I have some pipe. For example, I have this pipe:

```
user@user:~$ cal | head -1 | grep -oP "[A-Za-z]+"
```

For this pipe I get this result:

```
September
```

I want to store this result to a variable. I write the following commands:

```
user@user:~$ cal | head -1 | month=$(grep -oP "[A-Za-z]+") | echo $month
```

And I get the blank string. What is the problem?

Comment: With `bash` >= 4.2: `printf -v month "%(%B)T"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 month=$(cal | head -1 | grep -oP "[A-Za-z]+")
```

or

```
 month=$(date +%B)
```

Comment: thank you. This is work. But why I have a problem? I can not to redirect grep output to a variable?

Comment: This is not possible: `command1 | variable="$(commsn2)"`. Write `variable="$(command1 | command2)"`.

Comment: The second suggestion is a much better idea @Denis.